# Can someone explain below code to find pivot in sorted and rotated array? How one would arrive at below code?

Tags: arrays

I am trying to write code to find pivot in sorted and rotated array.I found below code working but don't understand what is the thought process to arrive at this code.If someone can explain?

```
int findPivot(int[] arr, int low,int high){
        if(arr.length==0) return -1; 
       // base cases 
       if (high < low)   
            return -1; 
       if (high == low)  
            return low; 

       /* low + (high - low)/2; */
       int mid = (low + high)/2;    
       if (mid < high && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]) 
           return mid;

       if (mid > low && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]) 
           return (mid-1); 

       if (arr[low] >= arr[mid]) 
           return findPivot(arr, low, mid-1); 
       return findPivot(arr, mid + 1, high); 
    }
```

Comment: If you are seeking help using a specific programming language, you should [edit] your question's tags to include what language you are using in your code sample. This helps users who are experienced with this language find and answer your question.